# can an invalid ssl certificate cause some posts to fail via ajax in firefox?

Tags: ajax, firefox, ssl

I'm wondering if an invalid or expired SSL certificate could cause some ajax posts via Firefox to fail (not all ajax posts, some are successful)?  I'm trying to determine the cause of my ajax request via firefox to be aborted (and is not seen in other browsers).  If I'm using Fiddler, the post does work too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, attempting to connect to an HTTPS site that has an invalid certificate (for whatever reason) with a XHR request will make this request fail. Unlike direct requests, it won't be able to display the usual certificate warning message to ask you whether you want to proceed.

Comment: Sounds logical, however, why would some ajax requests work (to the same method)?  And this only happens in firefox.  IE and Chrome work in all instances.  I would think it would happen for every ajax request to the same method while using firefox.